# ZF2 : 2 domains name in module.config.php

Tags: zend-framework

I use zend Framework 2 for a web site (domain1.ltd).
I would like to add a new domain name (domain2.ltd) pointing on this web site.

But domain2.ltd will have a different layout and some specific controller.

I try to modify the module.config.php in order to define new route for domain2.ltd but it doesn't switch like I want.

I try 
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html
with "Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname"

May be it's not the right way ??

Thanks for your advice?

Comment: After more test. If I specify an explicite route (for ex : 'sd1.domain.net') for the 2 route, it works fine !

Comment: Could you explain your solution and validate it pls, or just close the question.